# WPF ListBox, the SelectedIndex is not the highlighted row

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Weird situation, I've got the following XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBlock>Logging here...</TextBlock>
  <ListBox x:Name="LoggingListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Log}" />
</StackPanel>
```

My source is just 5 lines of text in an `ObservableCollection<string>`, and I select the 4th row:

```
LoggingListBox.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

But it displays as follows:

[image: Weird...]

As you can see, the 3rd item does have a border, but why is the first row highlighted?

Anybody got a clue what's going on?

---

**Update 1/17/17:**
I've made a smaller demo version of the problem.

1) New WPF project

2) MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxSelectionTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>Logging here...</TextBlock>
        <ListBox x:Name="LoggingListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Log}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

3) Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow 
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Log { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        Log = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Log.CollectionChanged += (o, e) => LoggingListBox.SelectedItem = Log.Last();

        Log.Add("Adding instrument: Unknown:#22");
        Log.Add("Adding instrument: Unknown:#22");
        Log.Add("Adding instrument: Unknown:#22");
        Log.Add("Adding instrument: Unknown:#22");
        Log.Add("Adding instrument: Unknown:#22");
    }
}
```

4: Run program:
Looks like this on startup:

[image: Wrong selection example #1]

5: Hit the TAB button (sets focus to listbox), and now looks like:

[image: Wrong selection example #2]

I suspect I'm somehow setting the selection out of the proper order WPF really wants.

Comment: That's strange, if it's the only code that's in play, everything should work. What `SelectionMode` do you use? Do you do anything else with selection apart from setting SelectedIndex? Where do you call the change of selected index (i.e. button click handler)?

Answer (score 0):

After your edits it's more clear what's going on in your case.

First, note that making this small test change to your example fixes the issue:

```
Log.Add("Adding instrument: Unknown:#22");
Log.Add("Adding instrument: Unknown:#23");
Log.Add("Adding instrument: Unknown:#24");
Log.Add("Adding instrument: Unknown:#25");
Log.Add("Adding instrument: Unknown:#26");
```

Every string is different now. So the reason for the first line being grey\blue is because ListBox can't distiguish them, basically.

But why we have dotted border then? Well, that's because it's drawn by another mechanism - [FocusVisualStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And it seems to track selected visual element correctly.

There are different possible solutions for the situation, but why not just move the selection logic to indexes and be done with it?

```
LoggingListBox.Loaded += (o, e) =>
    {
        Log.CollectionChanged += (oo, ee) => SelectLastEntry();
        SelectLastEntry();
    };

...

private void SelectLastEntry()
{
     LoggingListBox.SelectedIndex = LoggingListBox.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your item it selected but not highlighted. You can try to highlight to  cyan when focused.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Cyan"/>
```

and gray when not focussed.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Gray" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The `ListBox` is designed to handle multiple selections and highlights are a separate situation. You will also need to scroll it into view to change the highlight to the selected such a

```
LoggingListBox.ScrollIntoView(LoggingListBox.Items[3]);
```